# Can I attach heavy glass enclosure to plastic shower

Tags: bathroom, shower, glass, plastic

The shower surround is attached to studs but where the heavy glass enclosure should attach there are no studs. Is there some kind of anchor I can use to attach to the plastic only?
Thank you!

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. If an answer is helpful, please click the large check mark next to it to accept. And, please [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Glass shower enclosures are typically supported by the walls and specifically studs in the walls. Often they will be attached through the shower surface (tile, granite, etc.) if it's structurally sound. Glass is **heavy**. The biggest issue is typically with the door because it is hinged (suspended) on one side. Some of the weight of the door can be offset with metal framing around the glass enclosure and the door. However, the door must be fastened into a supporting wall stud and preferably a double stud.
The short answer here is **No!** You don't want to try to mount glass directly to a plastic shower enclosure. You need to get a professional involved here if you haven't worked with this before. If it's not mounted properly it can be dangerous.

Comment: I agree, normally a few holes are drilled through the surround. To attach the framework for the enclosure. I have seen 1 that was supposed to expand and hold itself in place (diy).  I was there to clean up and install a new enclosure after the owner got 4-6 stitches and it was tempered glass.+